# Apply color for each and every point in PointCloud Using HelixToolkit

Tags: c#, sharpdx, point-clouds, helix-3d-toolkit, helix

I have created a point cloud in **HelixToolKit**. I need to apply color for each and every point . When I am using **PointVisual3D** there is no options for setting color for each and every point . It set color for the whole point cloud.
When I am using **PointGeometryModel3D** (using SharpDX) inside the Helix tool kit also I cant able to **set the color for each and every point**. There is any possibility to set the color for each and every point in Point Cloud.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? The proposed code from TheTrasher is not working for me (black points). As you have marked it as accepted answer, could you explain how did you make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, this is done by setting the Colors property in the PointGeometry3D object of your PointGeometryModel3D. You have to build the Geometry on your own.

1. Create the render positions
2. Create the colors
3. Tell the renderer the order of your position and colors (List indices in Positions/Colors)

   ```
          //create PointGeometryModel3D object
       PointGeometryModel3D pgm = new PointGeometryModel3D();

       //create positions
       pgm.Geometry.Positions = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Core.Vector3Collection();

       pgm.Geometry.Positions.AddRange(
           new SharpDX.Vector3[]
           {   new SharpDX.Vector3(0,1,2), 
               new SharpDX.Vector3(1,2,3), 
               new SharpDX.Vector3(3,2,3), 
           });

       //create colors
       pgm.Geometry.Colors = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Core.Color4Collection();

       pgm.Geometry.Colors.AddRange(
           new SharpDX.Color4[]
           {   
               new SharpDX.Color4(1f,0,0,1), 
               new SharpDX.Color4(0,1f,0,1), 
               new SharpDX.Color4(0,0,1f,1) 
           });

       //create indices
       pgm.Geometry.Indices = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.Core.IntCollection();

       pgm.Geometry.Indices.AddRange(
           new int[]
           {   
               0,
               1,
               2,
           });
   ```

Please let me know if it worked for you. I couldn't make it work with LineGeometry3D and different line colors. There must somewhere be an option to make the renderer use the Color vertices instead of the (single) color property.